# Range string as integer

Tags: php, string, elasticsearch, integer

Let's say we have **Post** index that has nested **parameters** field with strict mapping and having the following structure

```
    "parameters": {
        "type": "nested",
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
          "kind": {
            "type": "text",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "label": {
            "type": "text",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "option_id": {
            "type": "text",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "include_in_all": true
          }
        }
      },
```

Value property can handle both integer, float and string values. But, now I have to filter posts by **parameters.value**, particularly using **range query**(parameters.value > $needing_value). I am tried to use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html). According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html#_ranges_on_strings) **parameters.value** would be filtered lexicographically. But I need to search as integer. So what can I do to reach my needles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only natural way is to index different types in different properties. You can use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html